# Problema con interfaz- Java

Tags: java

Cuando implemento una interfaz en diferentes clases no se como acceder a una variable de alguna de las clases

```
public interface Enganchable {

    void enganchar(Enganchable E);

    void desenganchar();
}
public class Locomotora implements Enganchable {
    public int numero;
    public Enganchable primerVagon;
}
public class Tren {
    public Enganchable locomotora;
    public Enganchable ultimoVagon;
}
```

suponiendo que luego quisiera hacer esto

```
t1.locomotora.numero = Integer.valueOf(kboar.nextLine());
```

tengo un error en numero y no se como accederlo para modificarlo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La única manera sería modificar el tipo del atributo:

La clase `Tren` tiene dos atributos `Enganchable`: `locomotora` y `ultimoVagon`.

Asumiendo que los vagones son de la clase `Vagon` y cumplen la interfaz `Enganchable`, pero no tienen `número`, podrías hacer algo como

```
Tren t= new Tren();
t.locomotora= new Vagon();
```

Como puedes ver, nada asegura que el objeto del atributo `locomotora` tenga el atributo `numero`, por tanto Java no te dejará intentar usarlo.

La solución es sencilla:

Es lógico que `Locomotora` implemente `Enganchable`, pero si el atributo ya se llama así, `locomotora`, es lógico pensar que sólo debería aceptar la clase `Locomotora`:

```
public class Tren {
    public Locomotora locomotora;
    public Enganchable ultimoVagon;
}
```

Esto te obliga a tener una locomotora (lo que suena lógico), pero te permite meter una segunda locomotora como un objeto Enganchable más.

También podrías hacer un casting, pero puesto que la locomotora será siempre una Locomotora, lo veo innecesario:

```
Locomotora loco = (Locomotora) t1.locomotora;
```

Si recorres la lista de `Enganchables`, podrás buscar las locomotoras así:

```
Enganchable aux=... //asignas el siguiente Enganchable de tu tren

if (aux instanceof Locomotora) {
    Locomotora l = (Locomotora) aux;
    l.numero= ...
}
```

Comment: Un comentario a modo consulta , ¿Es muy comun hacer casteos cuando uno aplica interfaces como en este caso?o poniendolo de otra manera ¿En programacion cuando uno aplica una interface lo mas probable que uno se cruce con un casteo de forma casi inevitable?

Comment: No es extremadamente raro pero no se suelen hacer, generalmente no es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a los atrubutos de una clase tienes que generar los Gets y Sets,

Ej;

```
public class Tren {
public Enganchable locomotora;
public Enganchable ultimoVagon;

public Enganchable getLocomotora(){
return locomotora;
 }
}
```

y para acceder, desde otra clase, tienes que crear una instancia hacia el objeto de esa clase;

```
 Enganchable nombreVariable;
 Tren miTren = new Tren();
 nombreVariable =   miTren.getLocomotora();
```

Comment: El atributo `locomotora` y, a su vez, el atributo `numero` están declarados como `public`. Usar un setter y un getter es una buena idea, pero no es el origen del error y no solucionaría nada.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es untroducir un nuevo numero de locomotora no?

Comment: Está intentando introducir un número a un Enganchable, que no tiene el atributo número definido